# Use Eclipse to generate the java Classes corresponding to a ASN.1description

Tags: java, eclipse, asn.1

I installed this ASN.1 editor plugin to in my Eclipse and i wrote this code

Editor http://asneditor.sourceforge.net

> -- Created: Mon May 06 19:38:15 CEST 2013 ASN-Module DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= BEGIN
>
> Client ::= SEQUENCE { lientNumber INTEGER}
>
> Server ::= SEQUENCE { lientNumber INTEGER, serverString String } END

But I don't found how to use this Editor to generate the java Classes corresponding to my ASN.1 description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an ASN compiler for that. You can try this one:

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/jac-asn1/

Answer (score 0):

A glance at the website suggests this plugin does not have the functionality you desire. It appears to be designed to make it easier to write ASN.1 grammars, but not to generate Java code for them.

I would suggest you Google for "*asn1 java compiler*" and try some of the current popular options.

Comment: The "Legion of the Bouncy Castle" library has ASN.1 encoding and decoding classes, but it has no annotation-based binding scheme.  Look at http://www.bitpapers.com/2012/04/bouncy-castle-asn1-api.html .